# Why would Esc-p or Ctrl-p not work in one terminal but work in all the others?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, xterm

Somehow, when I start my X session in Ubuntu 16.04, I get a Gnome Terminal window with 6 tabs and they all works as expected except for the last tab. That one loses the <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> functionality.

Since it works in the other 5 tabs, my idea would be that's because it is the last tab. At the same time, if I close that tab and reopen a new one, that new one works as expected.

That terminal window gets opened automatically whenever I open my X session.

Another thing that does not work either is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>. The first time I hit that one, I get a `^D` in the console and it does not get killed.

As a side note, one thing that I do in my `.bashrc` is `stty -ctlecho` so I do not get the `^C` all the time (which otherwise prevents me from using copy/paste!) So it feels like that specific like does not get executed since I see the `^D` when typing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> key in the console.

What could be going wrong?

The concerned binaries:

```
alexis   23335 22889  0 08:31 ?        00:00:22 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
alexis   23376 23335  0 08:31 pts/19   00:00:00 bash
alexis   23377 23335  0 08:31 pts/20   00:00:00 bash
alexis   23378 23335  0 08:31 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
alexis   23379 23335  0 08:31 pts/22   00:00:00 bash
alexis   23387 23335  0 08:31 pts/23   00:00:00 bash
alexis   23430 23335  0 08:31 pts/24   00:00:00 bash
alexis   24960 23335  0 08:53 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
alexis   25387 23335  0 09:02 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
```

Comment: Could you please clarify which terminal emulator and how you are using exactly? `xterm` does not support tabs, so it's either not `xterm`, or not tabs that you have.

Comment: @egmont, ah... I always think of it as an `xterm` since I'm under X and that's a terminal. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out today what the problem is.

I changed my prompt a few days ago to include time (`H:M:S`) after the current path, so that way I can see when I ran a command. This is useful when I want to have an idea of how long a command takes without having to each time think of using `/usr/bin/time`.

This addition made the length of the prompt that much longer (9 more characters, with the space) and the <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> functionality gets turned off because it decides that the position of the cursor is too far away from column 1.

If I do:

```
cd ..
```

just once, the length of the prompt is reduced just enough that the functionality returns!

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> still works.

Comment: Did you found a solution to make it work?

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud Well, short of using Ctrl-R, not really.

Answer (score 0):

changed my ~/.inputrc in vi editing mode with following configuration

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set show-all-if-unmodified on

set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert

"\C-p":previous-history
"\C-n":next-history
"\C-a.":beginning-of-line
"\C-e.":end-of-line

"\C-l":clear-screen
```